# How can I implement this awesome three.js code into my Next.js app

Tags: next.js, three.js, background, interactive

I want this as background of my login panel: https://codepen.io/soju22/pen/PLeLwo

I got this error from next.js

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
ReferenceError: THREE is not defined

Call Stack
App
/js/wave.js (20:17)
<unknown>
/js/wave.js (1:1)
```

I tried with `<Script>` tag what Next.js provide but site says what I wrote before.

I never played with threejs before.